# A cryptic ranking of the US-states

Tags: pattern, geography, knowledge

I have ranked the US-states according to a certain cryptic property
and put them into a list.  A contiguous piece of this cryptic list
looks as follows:

> ..., ?????, Nevada, West Virginia, Kansas, Oregon, Minnesota,
>   California, Wisconsin, Iowa, Texas, Florida, Michigan,
>   Arkansas, Missouri, Maine, Alabama, Illinois, ?????, ...

**Which states are represented by ????? ?**
**What is the cryptic property?**

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer depends on an arbitrary list of states found on another web site.  Remove that web page and there is no answer.

Comment: @FlorianF There is a property behind the list though that isn't restricted to just that site. Gamow's answer, although it wasn't accepted as the best one, explains this more clearly.

Comment: Indeed, that is better than I thought.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Solution**

> Nebraska and Mississippi

**Description**

> The most enraging Starbucks order I’ve ever witnessed and a mnemonic for the 50 states in order of statehood

Found on http://goo.gl/x1CXdi with

> google query: "Nevada, West Virginia, Kansas, Oregon, Minnesota, California" ...

Answer (score 3):

- The cryptic property is:

  > the **date of statehood** (the date of admission to the union).
  > http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states_by_date_of_admission_to_the_Union
  > The list has the statehood dates ordered upside down: the younger states come at the beginning, the later states come at the end
- The first missing state is:

  > **Nebraska** (admission date = March 1, 1867).
- The second missing state is:

  > **Mississippi** (admission date = December 10, 1817).